# {url_title} In URL, and Edit Form on Next Page

Tags: safecracker, segments, membrr

having a bit of trouble getting the url_title from the filled out safecracker form to appear correctly, here is what i have:

```
{exp:safecracker
channel="personal_trainer_directory"
entry_id=""
safecracker_head="no"
use_live_url="no"
url_title=""
}
{exp:membrr:subscriptions}
<span id="ptmember">
    <a href="{site_url}member/update-personal-trainer-page/{subscription_id}/{url_title}/">Update Personal Trainer Page</a>
</span>
{/exp:membrr:subscriptions}
{/exp:safecracker}
```

im trying to get the name to appear in the segment and then on the next page will be the safecracker where i can put {segment_4} for the url_title so the form will be able to edit the entry.. but with the way it is now, nothing is showing up for {url_title}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your safecracker tag should contain the complete `url_title="{segment_4}"` (if url_title is  empty, you get an empty form).

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#id3

Comment: how do I get the url_title into the url though? thats what I was trying to do with `<a href="{site_url}member/update-personal-trainer-page/{subscription_id}/{url_title}/">Update Personal Trainer Page</a>` that way on the next page, where the edit form will be, I could use `{segment_#}` for the `url_title` value

Comment: I'd say it's already in the link. What happens when you click the link? What url do you get?

Comment: I get `site.com/member/update-personal-trainer-page/1032//` the url_title displays as blank

Comment: I think it's a membrr thing: http://www.membrr.com/docs/template_tags. It looks like the {url_title} is not available, but you can use the {entry_id} tag...